# Storyboard view IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here :)?

For some reason the view as it is on the storyboard doesn't show the same in the simulator.

[image]

Screendumb:

http://s12.postimage.org/qe69tndel/Sk_rmbillede_2013_02_09_kl_20_41_49.png

Comment: It looks like those are two different height screens, and you have some autolayout constraints possibly wrong. Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: What kind of details do you need? And where do I check this autolayout constraint?

Comment: Well, are you using autolayout (that was a guess)? Did you set up your constraints in code or in the storyboard? What are those constraints for each of those 4 squares?

Comment: hmm, I dont know about auto layout, where do I check this? I set up the constraints in the storyboard,

Comment: It worked fine before I changed the buttons from round rected to custom

Comment: Autolayout constraints were broken when you changed the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many problems here including :

1)You are running the project on a 4-inch simulator, but your app probably doesn't have the default-568h@2x image, which is required so your app can be run full-screen on a 4-inch device.

2) If you're using auto-layout, probably the constraints aren't set right.

3) If you're not using auto-layout, probably the auto-resizing masks aren't set right

Comment: It was a problem with the constraints. Thanks your help!